# How can I test a functional React component's clickHandler using Jest and React Test Library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a functional button component (dumbed down from my actual button component) that has a `clickHandler` that fires whenever it is clicked. How can I test if that specific function gets called? I know I can create my own `const mockClickHandler = jest.fn();` and attach it to the button but I want to test the handler that already exists in the Button component.

```js
// Button.jsx

const Button = () => {
  const clickHandler = () => {
    // code
  }

  render(
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>
      Click Me
    </button>
  )
}
```

```js
// Button.spec.jsx

test('Click event functions properly', () => {
  const { getByRole } = render(<Button />)
  const button = getByRole('button');
  
  // ...
})
```

Comment: What is the click handler supposed to _do_? Test _that_ not the implementation detail of whether or not it's called.

Comment: What happens inside `clickHandler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this if you pass the clickHandler by props

```js
it('calls "onClick" prop on button click', () => {
  // Render new instance in every test to prevent leaking state
  const onClick = jest.fn();
  const { getByRole } = render(<Button onClick={onClick} />);

  fireEvent.click(getByText(/click me nao/i));
  expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you dont want to pass it by props you can test what happens with the DOM after that click.

Comment: This doesn't work for my Button component. For whatever reason, and probably having to do with having zero props, I'm unable to pass an event handler like that in my test. I want to test specifically for `onButtonClick`.